# Удаление строк T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Пытаюсь удалить строки в таблице обычным запросом с условием:

```
DELETE Orders
WHERE (OrderDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '1996-08-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND
(OrderDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '1996-08-30 00:00:00', 102))
```

Но при выполнении возникает ошибка:

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Order_Details_Orders". The conflict occurred in database "Northwind", table "dbo.Order Details", column 'OrderID'.
```

Я так понял, что две таблицы связаны внешним ключом, и так просто строки из этой таблицы не удалить. Подскажите, как можно их удалить, но не применяя каскадное удаление.

Comment: А какого результата Вы хотите добиться? Вот у вас в таблице `[Order Details]` есть строка с `OrderID = 1`. Ваш запрос удаляет из таблицы `Orders` строку с `ID = 1`. Что должно произойти с той строкой из `[Order Detais]`? Должна тоже удалиться? Или `OrderID` должен измениться на `NULL`? Или `OrderID` должен стать, например, 2? Или должно произойти что-то другое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала удалите все записи из `Order_Details`:

```
delete from Order_Details where orderId in (  
  select Id from orders where WHERE (OrderDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '1996-08-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND  
(OrderDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '1996-08-30 00:00:00', 102)))
```

А потом уже удаляйте записи из `Orders`.

И оберните  в транзакцию

Но чем Вам не понравилось каскадное удаление? Оно как раз для этого придумано.